# Allure report logged only the first fail and the test ends and doesn't run all steps after the first fail

Tags: report, allure

I'm using Java+TestNG+Allure. I need to get all test fails in Allure report, not only the first fail of the test but all, and the test should run from the beginning to the end despite failed steps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

For reporting the test failures in Allure report we have to do little bit of modifications in Allure Class. Here we want to report any of the sub step as a failure, execute the remaining steps and then mark the main test step as a failed test. For doing this we can use the concept of SoftAssertions. I had created one class called as AllureLogger. Inside the class we will have 5 Methods.
1)starttest() 2)endtest() 3) markStepAsPassed(String message) 4)marstepAsFailed(String message) 5)logStep().

```java
    public class AllureLogger {
        public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoylog");
        private static StepResult result_fail;
        private static StepResult result_pass;
        private static String uuid;
        private static SoftAssert softAssertion;


        public static void startTest() {
            softAssertion = new SoftAssert();
        }

        public static void logStep(String discription) {
            log.info(discription);
            uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            result_fail = new StepResult().withName(discription).withStatus(Status.FAILED);
            result_pass = new StepResult().withName(discription).withStatus(Status.PASSED);
        }

        public static void markStepAsFailed(WebDriver driver, String errorMessage) {
            log.fatal(errorMessage);
            Allure.getLifecycle().startStep(uuid, result_fail);
            Allure.getLifecycle().addAttachment(errorMessage, "image", "JPEG", ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES));
            Allure.getLifecycle().stopStep(uuid);
            softAssertion.fail(errorMessage);
        }


        public static void markStepAsPassed(WebDriver driver, String message) {
            log.info(message);
            Allure.getLifecycle().startStep(uuid, result_pass);
            Allure.getLifecycle().stopStep(uuid);
        }

        public static void endTest() {
            softAssertion.assertAll();
            softAssertion = null;
            startTest();
            softAssertion = new SoftAssert();
        }

    }
```

In the above class, we are using different methods from allureClass and we are doing little bit of modification to add soft assertions.

Everytime we start a TestMethod in testClass we can call the starttest() and end testmethod().Inside the test methods if we have some substeps we can use try catch block to mark the substeps as pass or fail.Ex-Please check the below test method as an Example

```java
    @Test(description = "Login to application and navigate to Applications tab ")
        public void testLogin() 
        {
            AllureLogger.startTest();
            userLogin();
            navigatetoapplicationsTab();
            AllureLogger.endTest();
        }
```

Above is a test method which will login to one application and then navigate to application tab.Inside we have two methods which will be reported as substeps, 1)login()-  For logging in the application 2) navigatetoapplicationsTab()-to navigate to application tab. If any of the substep fails then the main step and substep will be marked as fail and remaining steps will be executed.

We will define the body of the above functions which are defined in test method as below:

```
userLogin()
{
  AllureLogger.logStep("Login to the application");
  try
  {
    /*
 Write the logic here
    */
AllureLogger.MarStepAsPassed(driver,"Login successful");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
{
AllureLogger.MarStepAsFailed(driver,"Login not successful");
}
}


navigatetoapplicationsTab()
{
  AllureLogger.logStep("Navigate to application Tab");
  try
  {
    /*
 Write the logic here
    */
AllureLogger.MarStepAsPassed(driver,"Navigate to application Tab successful");
  }
  catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
AllureLogger.MarStepAsFailed(driver,"Navigate to application Tab failed");
}
}
```

Everytime any exception is thrown they will be caught in catch block and reported in the Allure Report. The soft assertion enables us to execute all the remaining steps successfully.

Attached is a screenshot of an Allure report generated by using the above technique.The main step is marked as Failed and remaining test cases have got executed.

[image: AllureReport]

The report attached here is not from the above example which is mentioned. It is just a sample as how the report would look.

Comment: When it hits this line softAssertion.assertAll(); it throws the below exception java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.AssertionError cannot be cast to java.lang.Exception. Any suggestion please?